# What is "TargetCore" in a .Net memory trace?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, memory, memory-leaks

I'm debugging a memory leak in a C# .Net project, using Visual Studio 2015. When I look at the "Paths to Root" for the object with the most growth, I'm seeing `TargetCore<MyCustomClass> [Local Variable]` at the innermost level. Some quick searching didn't turn up anything on `TargetCore`. What is it, and what meaning can I draw from that (how does it help me solve why instances of `MyCustomClass` are leaking)?

Comment: There's no subclass, TargetCore`1 is sealed

Comment: Hm.. and if you see only these objects, then that may mean that actually something else is holding those TargetCores that hold your objects. Try finding what holds those TCs, maybe it will explain it. If it is a data-flow, maybe there are some registered continuations for them, and maybe they never fired off yet due to some reason? Also, there's slight chance that what we see on GitHub is NOT the same .Net version as what you are using!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See for yourself: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/src/Internal/TargetCore.cs

While I cannot tell you for sure, there's a comment `Provides a core implementation`, so this class is actually a `Target<TInput>`. Judging from ns `System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow` and some methods like `OfferMessage`/`SignalOneAsyncMessageCompleted`, I suppose it is actually a `MessageTarget` class that acts as an aggregation point or completion point for async operations.

But, that's my half-educated guess, so if your problem is critical, please don't rely on what I write too much without some other confirmation. Also, that's why I mark this as 'wiki' answer :) It's really mostly a guess.